# Send parameters to java class from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, web, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a Jsp page and servlet which basically accepts the value for number of cities and next for matrix. My servlet takes the input value as string convert it into integer and store it in a two dimensional array

> Index.jsp

```
<body>
<form action="sample" method="post">
    <h1>Travelling Salesman Problem</h1>
    <input placeholder="Number of Cities" type="text" name="cities" required="">
    <input placeholder="Matrix" type="text" name="matrix" required="">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

> Servlet

```
public class sample extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        int city = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cities"));
        String numbers = request.getParameter("matrix");
        String[] splitText = numbers.split(" ");
        int[] mat = new int[splitText.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
            mat[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitText[i]);

        }

        int array2d[][] = new int[city][city];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < city; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < city; j++) {

                if (count == mat.length)
                    break;
                array2d[i][j] = mat[i * city + j];
                count++;


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Now i want to pass these parameters city and array2d to the following java class

```
public class TSPNearestNeighbour
{
private int numberOfNodes;
private Stack<Integer> stack;

public TSPNearestNeighbour()
{
stack = new Stack<Integer>();
}
public void tsp(int adjacencyMatrix[][])
{
numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[1].length - 1;
int[] visited = new
int[numberOfNodes + 1];
visited[1] = 1;
stack.push(1);
int element, dst = 0, i;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
boolean minFlag = false;
System.out.print(1 + "\t");

while (!stack.isEmpty())
{
element = stack.peek();
i = 1;
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
while (i <= numberOfNodes)
{
if
(adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0)
{



if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i])
{
min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
dst = i;
minFlag = true;
}
}
i++;
}
if (minFlag)
{
visited[dst] = 1;
stack.push(dst);
System.out.print(dst +"\t");
minFlag = false;
continue;
}


stack.pop();
}
}

public static void main (String... arg)
{
int number_of_nodes;
Scanner scanner = null;
try
{
```

> number_of_nodes = city //here i want to pass the city parameter

```
int adjacency_matrix[][] = new int[number_of_nodes + 1][number_of_nodes +1];



for (int i = 1; i <=number_of_nodes; i++)
{
for (int j = 1; j <=number_of_nodes; j++)
{
```

> adjacency_matrix[i][j]= array2d[i][j] // and here the array 2d parameter

```
}
}
for (int i = 1; i <=number_of_nodes; i++)
{
for (int j = 1; j <=number_of_nodes; j++)
{
if
(adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1 && adjacency_matrix[j][i] == 0)
{


adjacency_matrix[j][i] = 1;
}
}
}
System.out.println("the citys are visited as follows");
TSPNearestNeighbour tspNearestNeighbour = new TSPNearestNeighbour();
tspNearestNeighbour.tsp(adjacency_matrix);
} catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatch)
{
System.out.println("Wrong Input format");
}
scanner.close();
}
}
```

So how can we pass on these parameters from a servlet?
And where to include this class? In the servlet itself or create a separate class, as I'm using intellij. So please guide me through this.

Comment: Where is that "program" running?

Comment: Where do you want to pass them?

Comment: Actually this is where even I'm confused.. If I separately run the program by creating separate .java file in intellij and run. It's working fine by accepting command line inputs. So I wanted a web interface for that and my progress is this. So how to pass these inputted parameters exactly to program? So, please guide me on this.

Comment: @Jonathan I have highlighted the place where I want to pass the argument,please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing some logical errors in your code, but I'm not going into that context and I don't know what you are trying to do(On the processing side). But I'll try to cover the actual question you are asking, like "how to pass the jsp parameters to your another class".

So you can directly pass the strings as an argument to the another class like I've shown in the below code. I think I don't need to explain further you can see the code you will get it.

First your Servlet code: **Sample.java**

```
package com.server.testing;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

            String city = request.getParameter("cities");
            String numbers = request.getParameter("matrix");

            String[] args = new String[2];
            args[0] = city;
            args[1] = numbers;
            TSPNearestNeighbour.main(args);

    }
}
```

Now your another java class: **TSPNearestNeighbour.java**

```
package com.server.testing;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Stack;

public class TSPNearestNeighbour {
    private int numberOfNodes;
    private Stack<Integer> stack;

    public TSPNearestNeighbour() {
            stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    }

    public void tsp(int adjacencyMatrix[][]) {
            numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[1].length - 1;
            int[] visited = new int[numberOfNodes + 1];
            visited[1] = 1;
            stack.push(1);
            int element, dst = 0, i;
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            boolean minFlag = false;
            System.out.print(1 + "\t");

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    element = stack.peek();
                    i = 1;
                    min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    while (i <= numberOfNodes) {
                            if (adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0) {

                                    if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i]) {
                                            min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
                                            dst = i;
                                            minFlag = true;
                                    }
                            }
                            i++;
                    }
                    if (minFlag) {
                            visited[dst] = 1;
                            stack.push(dst);
                            System.out.print(dst + "\t");
                            minFlag = false;
                            continue;
                    }

                    stack.pop();
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            if(args.length<2) {
                    System.out.println("Two arguments required <city> <numbers>");
                    System.exit(-1);
            }

            int number_of_nodes=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            String[] splitText = args[1].split(" +");
            int[] mat = new int[splitText.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
                mat[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitText[i]);

            }



            try {
                    int adjacency_matrix[][] = new int[number_of_nodes + 1][number_of_nodes + 1];
                    int count = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++) {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++) {
                                    if (count == mat.length)
                                            break;
                                    adjacency_matrix[i][j]=  mat[(i-1) * number_of_nodes + (j-1)];
                                    count++;
                            }
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++) {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++) {
                                    if (adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1 && adjacency_matrix[j][i] == 0) {

                                            adjacency_matrix[j][i] = 1;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println("the citys are visited as follows");
                    TSPNearestNeighbour tspNearestNeighbour = new TSPNearestNeighbour();
                    tspNearestNeighbour.tsp(adjacency_matrix);
            } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatch) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Input format");
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: According to my logic the java class is working fine. I just wanted to know regarding passing values. So, i will try what you have explained and let me see.

Comment: Okay let me know if it worked (and you can accept the answer if it worked)